# Copy emails from Outlook folder to system folder

Tags: vba, outlook

I am using the below VBA code in Outlook to copy the selected emails to system folder. Instead of selecting emails I need to modify the code to copy all the emails from a particular folder in Outlook.

```
' General Declarations
Option Explicit

' Public declarations
' Public Enum olSaveAsTypeEnum
  'olSaveAsTxt = 0
  'olSaveAsRTF = 1
  'olSaveAsMsg = 3
'End Enum

Sub UATExport_MailasMSG()
' Routine will take all selected mails and export them as .MSG files to the
' directory defined by
' Error Handling
On Error Resume Next

' Varaiable Declarations
Dim objItem As Outlook.MailItem
Dim strExportFolder As String: strExportFolder = "I:\Documents\Dscan\"
Dim strExportFileName As String
Dim strExportPath As String
Dim objRegex As Object
Dim OldName As String, NewName As String

' Initiate regex search
Set objRegex = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
With objRegex
.Pattern = "(\s|\\|/|<|>|\|\|\?|:)"
.Global = True
.IgnoreCase = True
End With


' Check if any objects are selected.
If Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Count = 0 Then
   MsgBox ("No item has been selected.")
Else
    ' Cycle all selected objects.
    For Each objItem In Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection
        ' If the currently selected item is a mail item we can proceed
        If TypeOf objItem Is Outlook.MailItem Then
            ' Export to the predefined folder.
            strExportFileName = objRegex.Replace(objItem.Subject, "_")
            strExportPath = strExportFolder & strExportFileName & ".txt"
            objItem.SaveAs strExportPath, olSaveAsTxt
            'MsgBox ("Email saved to: " & strExportPath)
            OldName = Dir(strExportPath)
    NewName = Left(strExportPath, Len(strExportPath) - Len(OldName)) & _
              Left(OldName, Len(OldName) - 4) & "DircanReportfor asmsmrwerwdb1u" & _
              CStr(Format(FileDateTime(strExportPath), "ddmmyyhhmmss")) & ".txt"
     Name strExportPath As NewName


' declaration to go with the others
Dim strEmailBodybackup As String

' this will go in your for loop
' Save the body so that we can restore it after.
strEmailBodybackup = objItem.Body

' Edit the body of the mail to suit needs.
objItem.Body = Replace(objItem.Body, "To", "Tscanfile", , 1, vbTextCompare)

' Process the export like in your question

' Restore the body of the original mail
objItem.Body = strEmailBodybackup
        Else
            ' This is not an email item.
        End If
    Next 'objItem
End If

' Clear routine memory
Set objItem = Nothing
Set objRegex = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The Folder class provides the [Items](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff864247(v=office.15).aspx) property which returns an Items collection object as a collection of Outlook items in the specified folder. Be aware, the index for the Items collection starts at 1, and the items in the Items collection object are not guaranteed to be in any particular order. So, you can iterate over all items in the folder using the Items collection.

If you need to find a particular set of items that corresponds to the conditon, you can use the [Find](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869662(v=office.15).aspx)/[FindNext](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff862482(v=office.15).aspx) or [Restrict](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869597(v=office.15).aspx) methods of the Items class.

The [Sort](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff866960(v=office.15).aspx) method sorts the collection of items by the specified property. For example:

```
Sub SortByDueDate() 
  Dim myNameSpace As Outlook.NameSpace 
  Dim myFolder As Outlook.Folder 
  Dim myItem As Outlook.TaskItem 
  Dim myItems As Outlook.Items  

  Set myNameSpace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI") 
  Set myFolder = myNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderTasks) 
  Set myItems = myFolder.Items 
  myItems.Sort "[DueDate]", False 
  For Each myItem In myItems 
    MsgBox myItem.Subject & "-- " & myItem.DueDate 
  Next myItem 
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Eugene!!.I have tried this but it is throwing some error.I think i have modified the code wrongly.Can you please modify my above code along with your solution.

Comment: What error are you talking about? Did you try to debug the code?

Comment: Yes. i have tried debugging.I am ver new to VB programming.Will it be possible for you to modify my above code along with your soluion.